# Making an ASP.NET MVC Ajax call with the use of Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

First off, thanks for taking the time to read.

I'm trying to delve into ASP.NET MVC at the moment, however i currently have no wish to use any type of JavaScript framework, so please, don't tell me how much easier it would be etc, in your answer.

I currently have a Javascript function that successfully makes an AJAX call, however i am struggling to understand why no values are being returned from the request.

The function is as follows.

```
function ajaxRequestUser(num) {
var ajax;

try {
    ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch(e) {
    try {
        ajax = new ActiveXObject(Msxml2.XMLHTTP);
    } catch(e){
        alert('old browser');
    }
}

ajax.readystatechange = function () {
    if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
        var queryResult = ajax.responseText;

        if (!queryResult) {
            alert('No Information.');
        } else {
            alert(queryResult);
        }
    }
}
   var requestString = "?user="+num;
   ajax.open("GET", "/Users/GetUser" + requestString, true);
   ajax.send(null);
}
```

The function is called via a separate function that simply does some UI modifications to allow for the display of the data.

The alerts are there at this point, because i was not receiving any data back from the call and i was testing to see if that part of the code was being hit at all (Don't go into the differences between Synchronous and Asynchronous.). No matter how long i waited the data being returned was not being returned, after breaking through the actual server side c#, i saw the data being sent back, but it was just never being received. Is there something in the code that was done wrong? Or am i going about receiving the inbound data in the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue related to my code, and it is solely an error based around the declaration of my ajax.event where the event is **onreadystatechange** as opposed to **readystatechange**